# What is the difference between the traditional test = method(arg) and test = send(method, arg)?

Tags: ruby

I am in the `Order` model of a Rails application, where I wish to invoke a method for an instance of the `Email` class.

This first method takes the instance of the `Email` class (in this example it is called `email`). It works just fine.

```
def recursive_search_mails(user, settings)
  emails = user.emails.where(:datetime.gte => self.datetime)

  emails.each do |email|
    notification = email.test_if_notification(user, settings)
    if notification == true
      email.destroy
      return
    end
    correspondance = email.test_if_correspondance(user, settings)
    if correspondance == true
      email.destroy
      return
    end
  end
end
```

A more concise version of the above code would be this one:

```
def recursive_search_mails(user, settings)
  emails = user.emails.where(:datetime.gte => self.datetime)

  emails.each do |email|
    %w(notification, correspondance).each do |type|
      is_type = email.send("test_if_#{type}", user, settings)
      if is_type == true
        email.destroy
        return
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, it raises this error:

```
2013-05-09T16:36:11Z 71266 TID-owr7xy0d0 WARN: undefined method `test_if_notification,' for #<Email:0x007fd3a3ecd9b0>
```

How can this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other answers deal with the comma, I'll address the difference between approaches.

You invoke methods with `send` when you don't know method name in advance (at "code-write" time, for the lack of compile-time). Or you do know, but performing "static" calls greatly increases complexity of the code (your case, with duplicated code). In such cases, dynamic invocation (`send`) is called for.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed, don't know if I should delete the question or who to reward with the answer. Of course I shouldn't put a comma in. But thanks @Sergio Tulentsev for a short summery of why send is usefull.

Comment: @JohnSmith1976: don't worry, it happens when you're new :)

Comment: Yep. Stackoverflow to the rescue :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `%w` literal prefix creates an array of tokens separated by *whitespace*.

You have `%w(notification, correspondence)` which includes the strings "notification," (**note the comma**) and "correspondence".

Get rid of the comma and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

You have an unwanted comma

Change

```
%w(notification, correspondance)
```

to

```
%w(notification correspondance)
```